# Unable to configure hive.exec hooks due to missing jar

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to use Hive and to switch databases using the 'use db' command.  My setup is Hadoop 2.4.0 and Hive 0.13.1.  I add the following 3 properties to a .settings file

```
set hive.exec.failure.hooks=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook;
set hive.exec.post.hooks=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook;
set hive.exec.pre.hooks=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook;
```

I then open hive command line, passing in the .settings file via 'hive -i my.settings' and then I get:

```
hive> use db;
hive.exec.pre.hooks Class not found:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook
FAILED: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
```

It seems there is a jar missing from my classpath.  I tried searching the web for a jar containing "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook" class, but have had no luck.  I tried adding all paths with jars in them from HIVE_HOME to yarn-site.xml via:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
    <value>
            ...
            /apps/hive/hive-0.13.1/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/*,
            /apps/hive/hive-0.13.1/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/storage-handlers/hbase/lib/*,
            /apps/hive/hive-0.13.1/hcatalog/share/webhcat/java-client/*,
            /apps/hive/hive-0.13.1/hcatalog/share/webhcat/svr/lib/*,
            /apps/hive/hive-0.13.1/lib/*
    </value>
 </property>
```

Still no luck.  Does anyone know is there some additional step I need to do configure these properties?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the jar is only available in the, as yet unreleased, Hive 0.14.0.  So I had to download and build Hive according to the directions on the [Hive Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveDeveloperFAQ).  Which is simply:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Phadoop-2
```

Once that was built I was able to do this:

```
  hive> add jar <HIVE_HOME>/ql/target
      > ;
```

Or by adding this property to hive-site.xml

```
    <property>
            <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
            <value>file:///<HIVE_HOME>/ql/target/hive-exec-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</value>
    </property>
```

I also found a nice slide share presentation about [plugins](http://www.slideshare.net/julingks/apache-hive-hooksminwookim130813).